# google sheets API V4 data validation for range using "List from a range"

Tags: api, validation, google-sheets

I'm trying to set a data validation for one cell `A1` using a "List from a range" to `B1:B5`

From this page, 
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#booleancondition

It seems to be `ONE_OF_RANGE`, but can't get the code to work. Not sure where to put the specified range for list `B1:B5`

There is no example of `ONE_OF_RANGE` and how to use it.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "setDataValidation": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 0
        },
        "rule": {
          "condition": {
            "type": "ONE_OF_RANGE",
            "values": [
              {

              }
            ]
          },
          ,
          "strict": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried:

```
"type": "ONE_OF_RANGE",

          "values": [{
             "userEnteredValue": "=Sheet1!B1:B5"}
```

I don't get an error when running it, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it to work.

```
data={
  "requests": [
    {
      "setDataValidation": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 1,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1
        },
        "rule": {
          "condition": {
            "type": "ONE_OF_RANGE",

          "values": [{
             "userEnteredValue": "=Sheet5!B1:B5"}
         ]
          },

          "strict": 'true'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have table name like "Table Name" (with white space and It cause 500 error.
Solution was add doublequotes `"userEnteredValue" => "='Table Name'!CK3:CK990"`